# jQuery: Uppercase first letter of several words and lowercase the rest

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I have this code on my WordPress site:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $.fn.capitalize = function () {
        var wordsToIgnore = ["adalah","agar","akibat","akan","ah","ala","alias","antara","apabila"],
        minLength = 2;

        function getWords(str) {
            return str.match(/\S+\s*/g);
        }

        this.each(function () {
            var words = getWords(this.value);
            $.each(words, function (i, word) {
            if (wordsToIgnore.indexOf($.trim(word)) == -1 && $.trim(word).length > minLength) {
                words[i] = words[i].charAt(0).toUpperCase() + words[i].slice(1);
            }
            });
            this.value = words.join("");
        });
        };

    document.body.onkeyup = function(e){
        if(e.which == 32){
            $('#fp_title').capitalize();
        }
    }
});
```

The code work very well. First letter of any words except "WordToIgnore" will capitalize. But I need function that will lowercase first letter of "WordToIgnore" too. So, when user type on the field (#fp_title), first letter of "WordToIgnore" will lowercase automatically and the first letter of the rest words will uppercase. How can I do that?

EXAMPLE:

("**adalah**" is WordToIgnore)

- "cara adalah sesuatu" should be "Cara adalah Sesuatu"
- "Cara Adalah Sesuatu" should be "Cara adalah Sesuatu"
- "Cara Adalah sesuatu" should be "Cara adalah Sesuatu"

The results should be the same.

In english:

("**or**" is WordToIgnore)

- "me or you" should be "Me or You"
- "Me Or You" should be "Me or You"
- "Me Or you" should be "Me or You"

Comment: On typing whole string should convert into lowercase? Or the first letter should be uppercase and rest should be lowercase, please explain it via proper example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Convert the word to lowercase before comparing in if condition and use else condition too, it will work as per your requirements.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $.fn.capitalize = function () {
        var wordsToIgnore = ["adalah","agar","akibat","akan","ah","ala","alias","antara","apabila"],
        minLength = 2;

        function getWords(str) {
            return str.match(/\S+\s*/g);
        }

        this.each(function () {
            var words = getWords(this.value);
            $.each(words, function (i, word) {
            if (wordsToIgnore.indexOf($.trim(word.toLowerCase())) == -1 && $.trim(word).length > minLength) {
                words[i] = words[i].charAt(0).toUpperCase() + words[i].slice(1);
            }else{
                words[i] = words[i].charAt(0).toLowerCase() + words[i].slice(1);
            }
            });
            this.value = words.join("");
        });
        };

    document.body.onkeyup = function(e){
        if(e.which == 32){
            $('#fp_title').capitalize();
        }
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="fp_title">
```

Comment: i checked with "Cara Adalah Sesuatu" and it is getting desired result of "Cara adalah Sesuatu", can you please recheck?

Comment: Oh, sorry. Actually your code work very well. var wordsToIgnore in my real code have a lot of words than the example above. Thank you for your help!!!